# Restrict Front Ended User access to Form entry only

Tags: database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a front end database that I want to restrict user access to only enter data into a form. I do not want them to be able to scroll through other entries via the form. How can I restrict this in Access 2007-2010?

Answer (score 1):

There's a property on the form called DataEntry
[DataEntry property documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dataentry-property-f4236759-27f6-4fcd-abb0-4aa4acd8fe87)

If you set it to True, it will only allow new additions, it will not show you other records.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form based on that table, and only include the fields you want them to be able to edit.  Alternatively, you can add all the fields (for visibility) and disable (in the field Properties) the ones you want to be excluded from edits.  They will still be visible on the form, but the data they display cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass`acFormAdd`as an`DataMode`argument on [DoCmd.OpenForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openform) to allow only adding records.

Second option: have a Where-Condtion in Recordsource that doesn't fetch data like`Where 0 = 1`. That will leave form empty as condition is never met.